# How to tell if a character code represents a printable character in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is there a way to tell if a character is printable in Dart?

Similar to `unicode.IsPrint()` in go.

See: https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsPrint

Note - this does need to support non-latin characters.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any existing way to do this, so I ported golang's `strconv.IsPrint()` function.

See: https://github.com/xxgreg/dart_printable_char

To use it, first add the dependency to your `pubspec.yaml`.

```
dependencies:
  printable_char:
    git: git://github.com/xxgreg/dart_printable_char.git
```

Then import the library and use it.

```dart
import 'package:printable_char/printable_char.dart';

main() {
  bool x = isPrintable('x'.codeUnitAt(0));
  print(x);
}
```